# need help for my jquery validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My problem is my code for form validation wont work. I need some help please what causes that makes the code not working. I get my code by watching youtube tutorials but mine inst working.

I use bootstrap 3 and jquery validation plugin 1.12.0

html:

```
<form>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col=md-12">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group form-control-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="firstname">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="firstname" type="text" />
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-control-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input class="form-control" name="lastname" type="text" />
                </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="col-sm-offset-2 btn btn-primary input-lg">Submit</button>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.col-sm-4').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Depending on where you've put your `.validate()` call, it might not be a bad idea to enclose it within a DOM Ready event handler.  Otherwise, your code is working perfectly fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/T98Jm/

Comment: @Sparky idk what u changed in my code but i copy the code in ur jsfiffdle and now its working :D

Comment: The only difference is that I added a DOM Ready event handler.  I suggest you study this.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Sparky put that as an answer so that i can up and vote it :D

Comment: **Quote user3671584:** _"@Sparky put that as an answer so that i can up and vote it :D"_ ~ Strange how you accept an incorrect answer after you say I found the solution to your problem.  This is nothing but a disservice to the community.  Anyway, I've voted to re-open your question because I acknowledge that my original vote to close was in error.

Comment: I'm viting to leave as closed. The question is still poorly formulated. "not working" means nothing, the code could be reduced to a much smaller snippet

Comment: @rds, yes, it could have been written much better (that's what the up/down votes are for).  However, the closed reason is technically incorrect.  The OP's code, which includes the `<script>` tags, clearly shows that the DOM ready event handler is missing and that's the root problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script links and script block used to call the plugin can be placed just before the closing body tag and your code works as is.

Comment: -1 because your answer is nothing but a series of random guesses and contains the same mistake as the OP's.    The OP's code was broken because he failed to use a DOM ready event handler.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:  *As per comments on the OP, this is the correct answer.  The OP simply forget to wrap his code in the DOM ready event handler.   Apparently, he's not happy about my vote to put his question on hold.  Since the original closed reason is technically incorrect, I voted to re-open.*

---

You need to enclose your code within a [DOM Ready event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Otherwise the HTML does not yet exist when the jQuery tries to manipulate it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  // <- DOM is ready for manipulation

        // your validate code here
        $('form').validate({
        ..... 

    });
</script>
```

Your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/T98Jm/

Comment: @user3671584, at first glance your question did not seem to contain enough information to diagnose the problem. I've since voted to "re-open" it. Did I solve your problem or not? According to your comments above, I did.